# JFrog Artifactory: Tracking Database Changes in Releasenotes

Tags: java, artifactory

We are using Artifactory OSS and are still on version 5.1
Our plan is to go to the professional but first upgrade to the latest release, to clean up our repositories before the upgrade. Unfortunately over the years we have done some "integration" on database level. This means we are having scripts that are reading and writing to the artifactory database - which is not really nice. In order to upgrade, we first want to check what has changed in order to know what we must take care first. We already went through the releasenotes but couldn't identify changes. Were could we get this information from?

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the Artifactory DB directly might be risky because of possible future changes in Artifactory.
In any case, you can do the following:

1. Download the latest Artifactory source code (jfrog-artifactory-oss-x-sources.tar.gz) from here: https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-zip
2. Extract the sources archive, and find the up-to-date DB SQL file that define all tables of Artifactory at the extracted directory (i.e. `jfrog-artifactory-6.16.0/storage/db/src/main/resources/mssql/mysql.sql`)